# Datagridview can't display datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this class (AddRecord) with a method to return a datatable:

```
public DataTable SelectRec(ComboBox cb, DateTimePicker dtp1, DateTimePicker dtp2)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqladpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStrings);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand myCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCmd.CommandText = "SelectAccountRecord";
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dtp1.Text);
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dtp1.Text);
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newspaper", cb.Text);
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqladpt.SelectCommand = myCmd;
        sqladpt.Fill(dt);
        sqladpt.Dispose();
        //DataSource = ds.Tables["[a]"].DefaultView;
    }
    catch { }

    return dt;
}
```

So I call this method in other to display the content of the datatable in my datagridview as below

```
AddRecord ad = new AddRecord();
dgvRecorOverview.DataSource= ad.SelectRec(cbNewspaperRO, dtpFromDate, dtpToDate);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have give `DataBind()` for your Grid after assign the `DataSource`

like this

```
dgvRecorOverview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `DataGridView.AutoGenereateColumns = true;` to create columns automatically based on the `DataTable` you set as `DataSource`. Check whether the `DataTable (dt)` you fill is having the expected rows and columns. If the `DataTable` is empty then obviously you don't see any data in the grid.